# MySQL - count active/inactive/banned users and sellect users based on status in one query

Tags: mysql

I have `users` table, and user can have one of the three statuses:

```
active (0)
inactive (1)
banned (2)
```

Is it possible to count all type of users separately and take only users for selected status in one query. For example I want to show information how many user are active / inactive / banned and show all active users?

The table structure is simple:

```
id | firstName | lastName | email | password | status
```

**I'm trying to achieve something like this:**

```
Active Users (10) | Inactive Users (2) | Banned Users (7)
```

List of all active users:

```
1) John Doe
2) John Doe
3) John Doe
4) ...
```

Comment: Could you add an example of what output you want, to clarify a bit?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Your preferred output is not something you would get from a simple query. What you're listing is easiest achieved by a couple of queries, and then handled programatically in your app.

Comment: @PerEnström - So one query for counting and one for selecting?

Comment: Can't think of a single query giving you all three counts this late in the day, I'd probably just go with one for each count.

Comment: But as Sebastian showed in his answer below, it is possible for someone with a more alert brain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to get your expected output with one single query (since the strcuture of the result is different). You have to use two different querys to get the expected information of the `users` table:

**1 - You can get the `status` overview with the following:**

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS active_users,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS inactive_users,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS banned_users
FROM users
```

**2 - To get all users with `status = 0` (active) you can use the following:**

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE status = 0
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=10732ceea32dbb3f267fa6afc2ed8c71)

Comment: This is what I am looking for :). Still have to use two queries, but it is a lot better solution then selecting everything, filtering based on status and counting. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

A short version of **Sebastian Brosch's** answer:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(status = 0) AS active_users, 
    SUM(status = 1) AS inactive_users, 
    SUM(status = 2) AS banned_users 
FROM users;
```