# Count total user that subscribe and unsubscribe at the same day

Tags: mysql

I want to count total user that subscribe and unsubscribe the service at the same day. 
The user will be the **MSISDN** and subscription will be **OperationType**. 
If user subscribe, OperationType = 1, and if the user unsubscribe, OperationType = 2. The user can subscribe and unsubscribe the service on the same day.

Subscribe : OperationType = 1
Unsubscribe : OperationType = 2

[Structure & Data of tbl_process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWtah.png)
Refer to my data. I have two same user (which is MSISDN) that subscribe and later unsubscribe to the service.

[This is my result based on query below. I somehow manage to get list of user that subscribe and unsubscribe on the same day. But now I want to count total user who got 2 OperationType, which is 1 & 2 (this is based on my query).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5YiM.png)

Below is my query:

```html
SELECT DISTINCT(msisdn), operationType
FROM tbl_process
WHERE DATE(RequestTS) = '2019-03-14'
AND STATUS = 3
ORDER BY msisdn;
```

Comment: is it possible to unsubscribe followed by subscribe, is it possible to subscribe,unsubscribe,subscribe on same day

Comment: Yes it is possible but it is ok as long as the user subscribe and unsubscribe on the same day.

Comment: There are too many possible permutaions (in my mind) for me to figure out how to code this. I suspect you need a more encompassing rule than subscribed and unsubscribed on same day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - count active/inactive/banned users and sellect users based on status in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43740454/mysql-count-active-inactive-banned-users-and-sellect-users-based-on-status-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINAL ANSWER. I GOT THE ANSWERRR YAY

```html
SELECT SUM(IF(x.sub > 0 AND x.unsub > 0, 1, 0)) AS Daychrn
FROM ( 
 SELECT DISTINCT(msisdn), 
 SUM(IF(operationtype='1', 1, 0)) AS sub, 
 SUM(IF(operationtype='2', 1, 0)) AS unsub 
 FROM tbl_process 
 WHERE processts LIKE '2019-04-14%' 
 AND STATUS =3 
 GROUP BY msisdn
) X;
```

Answer (score 0):

select DATE,count(*) from 
(select 
 date(RequestTs) as DATE,
 msisdn,
  count(distinct operationType) 
from 
  tbl_process t1 
group by 1 
 having count(distinct operationType) > 1
 ) a group by 1

select count(distinct msisdn) from 
(select 
 date(RequestTs) as DATE,
 msisdn,
  count(distinct operationType) 
from 
  tbl_process t1 
group by 1 
 having count(distinct operationType) > 1
 ) a group by 1

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select 
  count(*) 
from 
  tbl_process t1 
  inner join tbl_process t2 on DATE_FORMAT(t1.RequestTS, '%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(t2.RequestTS, '%m-%d') 
  and t1.msisdn = t2.msisdn 
  and t1.operationType = 1 
  and t2.operationType = 2;
```

Comment: The OP seems not to want users who unsubscribe and then subscribe on the same day (unless they unsubscribe again the same day)

Comment: @Strawberry where is that in description ?

Comment: @Strawberry I see the question asking ' I want to count user that Operation Type=1 and OperationType=2 .'

'I want to count total user that subscribe and unsubscribe the service at the same day.' is the first line

Comment: Which is why we ask for clarification

Comment: If you refer back my table structure, I have 2 same user (refer to MSISDN) and the user subscribe and unsubscribe on the same day. MSISDN is user phone number.

Comment: @NoImo same user with different OperationType right ? it will be counted as one.

your requirement is to get the number of users who subscribed and unsubscribed on the same day  right ?

Comment: I only need one day only. If you join like that, it will count all day. I tried to insert the date in join but the value is incorrect.